# How to keep focus on a checkbox that you're disabling

Tags: qt, go

I have a widget that displays a list of settings that a user can set by (un)ticking a checkbox. The process of enabling/disabling a setting can take some time, so I implemented a visual representation of "in progress" to avoid multiple clicks from user while job hasn't yet finished:

```
func CheckBoxTransaction(transaction func() error, checkBox *widgets.QCheckBox) {
    checkBox.SetEnabled(false)
    checkBox.Repaint()

    // transaction() sets the setting, can take a while
    if err := transaction(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        checkBox.SetChecked(!checkBox.IsChecked())
    }
    checkBox.SetEnabled(true)
}
```

However, a side-effect I didn't expect started to occur: when you tick any checkbox, the focus jumps to the next checkbox in the settings list because of the `checkBox.SetEnabled(false)`. That causes the app UI to feel jumpy as the focus on the next checkbox is noticable by eye.

How can I keep the focus from jumping from the checkbox I'm about to disable? Or is there a better way to achieve the effect I'm striving for (blocking user input for a time and making it visible that the input is blocked)?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use binary switch variable (named allowClickCheckBox)  which its default is true.
then have this code in handler of check box:

```
if (allowClickCheckBox == false)
{
    if(ui->myCheckbox->isChecked() )
        ui->myCheckbox->setCheckState(Qt::unChecked);
    return;
}

allowClickCheckBox = false;
...
//do your job
...
allowClickCheckBox = true;
```

sorry for my probably syntax mistakes.